# How to list all the files in 2 or more directories in R?

Tags: r

I want to select all the files(`all.files`) in three different folders and use a function on those files. So when I use a function or loop to loop over each of `all.files`, I should be able to get access to those files in their respective directories.How do I achieve this goal?
I did something like this, but did not work:

`bam.dir <- c("path1/ABAM/","path2/BBAM/","path3/CBAM/")`

```
all.files<-list.files(bam.dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
all.files <- Vectorize(list.files)(bam.dir)
```

This creates a vectorized version of `list.files`, allowing you to pass a vector of directories as the first argument.

Comment: but when I create a loop (for i in 1:length(all.files) it only gives me the number of directories and not the number of files.

Comment: @user277653 if you want the files from all the directories grouped together, you can probably just do `unlist(all.files)`

Comment: In doing so, I get the full path which I don't want to paste in the result column. I want to paste the file names only in the result column as extension to indicate which column belongs to which file.

Comment: @user277653 I don't what you're trying to do, but this gives a list of filenames in your directories.  Use `unlist(all.files, use.names=F)` to get a vector of those filenames.  Or just `lapply(bam.dir, list.files)`